# mongoose schema design issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Lets say there is an article, you can comment on the article, some other guy can reply to your comment and you can even receive a reply for your reply. You can receive up / down votes for each and every comment / reply / reply of a reply.

The way i want to retrieve the data is like the two top most voted comment will be the first, after that newest to oldest order. Pretty much like youtube video comment system.

I came up with a pretty strange schema (in my opinion), i would like to verify if it can be done better or not.

```
var articleSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, max: 16, min: 1 },
  body: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, max: 2000, min: 1 },
  author: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  votes: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  tags: { type: [], get: getTags, set: setTags },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, get: getDate },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, get: getDate },

  comments: [{
    body: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, max: 2000, min: 1 },
    author: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    likes: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    likesCount: { type: Number, 'default': 0 },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, get: getDate },
    updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, get: getDate },

    replies: [{
      body: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, max: 2000, min: 1 },
      author: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
      likes: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
      likesCount: { type: Number, 'default': 0 },
      createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, get: getDate },
      updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, get: getDate },

      replies: [{
        body: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, max: 2000, min: 1 },
        author: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
        likes: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
        likesCount: { type: Number, 'default': 0 },
        createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, get: getDate },
        updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, get: getDate }
      }]
    }]
  }]
});
```

haha :P As you can see `comments / replies / replies.replies` are quite the same. I think it can be done recursively, but I do want to preserve the response data shape like this: (without any perf. hungry object modifications)

```
{
  "_id": "55a549ba15bc2ae3098693c7",
  "author": { '.': '.' },
  "title": "test",
  "body": "test 2",
  "comments": [{
    "body": "asd",
    "author": { '.': '.' },
    "_id": "55a54b20c2dd34d41a98ffff",
    "replies": [{
      "body": "bsd",
      "author": { '.': '.' },
      "_id": "55a54ba45eec5a4321e842ae",
      "updatedAt": "2015-07-14T17:49:24.500Z",
      "createdAt": "2015-07-14T17:49:24.500Z",
      "likesCount": 0,
      "likes": [],
      "replies": [{
        "body": "bsd",
        "author": { '.': '.' },
        "_id": "55a54ba45eec5a4321e842ae",
        "updatedAt": "2015-07-14T17:49:24.500Z",
        "createdAt": "2015-07-14T17:49:24.500Z",
        "likesCount": 0,
        "likes": []
      }]
    }],
    "updatedAt": "2015-07-14T17:47:12.383Z",
    "createdAt": "2015-07-14T17:47:12.383Z",
    "likesCount": 0,
    "likes": []
  }],
  "updatedAt": "2015-07-14T17:41:14.877Z",
  "createdAt": "2015-07-14T17:41:14.877Z",
  "tags": [""],
  "votes": []
}
```

Also I wonder how perf. hungry the sorting of this will be. I probably should insert each document in the correct date order so when i run the query i will only need pick out the two most voted comment and insert to the top.

Comment: You might find MongoDB's [blog post](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/) on this exact topic a bit illuminating. :)

Comment: Cool, now i just have to get familiar with the mongoose api :P